# Convert DB2 date column to an Excel date number

Tags: sql, db2

I appologize for this simple question but cannot find a straight and simple answer and am going crazy.

I am running on DB2 and I want to

```
Select date_column from my_table
```

but I want to select date_column as number the way Excel does it. So for example: 2017-02-26 would show up as 43157.

date_column is a `DATE` type in my table.

Comment: Why is today 43157?

Comment: because if you format 26/02/2018 as number ... for example in excel the actual value is 43157

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the Excel 1900 date system, where the number of days is measured since January 1, 1900, you may try the following query which uses the `DAYS` function to find a date difference:

```
SELECT
    DAYS(date_column) - DAYS('1900-01-01') AS excel_date
FROM my_table;
```

Comment: I think the base is actually '1899-12-30'

Comment: @AlexK. Actually, I think it is `1900-01-01`, ([see here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214330/differences-between-the-1900-and-the-1904-date-system-in-excel)), but I recall there being some funkiness where a handful of the early dates were skipped for some reason.

Comment: Postgres and Oracle claim there are 43155 days between `1900-01-01`  and `2018-02-26`  but 43157 between `1899-12-30` and `2018-02-26` So I guess Alex K is right as Mike is expecting 43157 as the result

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Dates don't just magically appear or disappear, unless you're using Excel which an [infamous leap year bug](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/214326/excel-incorrectly-assumes-that-the-year-1900-is-a-leap-year), by which 1900 was incorrectly treated as a leap year.  This might be the origin of that `1899-12-30` start date.  It offsets the leap year bug, and works completely fine for any year greater than 1900 (I think).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Well, a full year magically appears when you look at Oracle's year zero :-)

Comment: Dates do appear and disappear, at least in Sweden. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_30